# Is it possible to have a preview while scripted rendering?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

Is there a way to have a preview of the rendered image during the render process (like the one you get after you press the render button) if the render process is started from a script with

```
bpy.ops.render.render()
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call the `render()` operator via *PyConsole* or *Text Editor*, a different default execution context is used. It is `'EXEC_DEFAULT'`.

In contrast, buttons in panels and also menu entries use `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` by default for operators.

You can override the execution context in layouts:

```
col = layout.column()
col.operator_context = 'EXEC_DEFAULT'
col.operator("render.render")
```

As well as in the console / editor:

```
bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

If you use an override and keyword arguments for an operator call, the order is:

```
bpy.ops.render.render({'dict': "override"}, # dictionary for context overriding
                      'EXECUTION_CONTEXT',  # a valid execution context
                      undo,                 # undo support (True or False)
                      keyword="argument_1", # first operator argument
                      ...)                  # more operator arguments follow here
```

Links:

- [Keywords and Positional Arguments](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.ops.html#keywords-and-positional-arguments)
- [Execution Context](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.ops.html#execution-context)
- [UILayout.operator_context](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator_context) and the example of [Calling a file selector](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Operator.html#calling-a-file-selector)
- [Invoke Function](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Operator.html#invoke-function)

Comment: Where did this info come from? I didn't see anything of this [here](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.ops.render.html?highlight=render#bpy.ops.render.render). Is there a way to preview the rendered image, yet only return once the render is done (to do multiple renders in a row)?

Comment: I added some references to the API docs. If you want to do something when rendering is done, you may wanna look into the [app handler](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.app.handlers.html) **render_complete**.